# Get cursor position in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm trying to get the cursor position in canavs when clicked but the following error pops into my console

```
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
```

here is my code:

```
$(".canvas-wrapper").click(function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
  var rectangle = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rectangle.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rectangle.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
});
```

I simply cannot understand what's wrong. Any help?

Comment: According to jQuery documentation, Your `getCursorPosition()` expects wrong arguments. See https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument that jQuery passes to your callback function is not the element but an event object. The element can be accessed via `this`.

From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler):

> #### handler
>
> **Type**: `Function( Event eventObject )`
> A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

You could change your code to this:

```
$(".canvas-wrapper").click(function getCursorPosition(event) {
  var rectangle = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rectangle.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rectangle.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
});
```